# Database Entity Relationship Modelling One to Many, Constant to Many?

Tags: sql, relational-database, data-modeling

I am wondering if I should treat a constant (for example) 22 in the same way as one, when it comes to generating look here relationship entities to a relational model, aka when generating foreign keys.
So for 'Player' to 'Match' it would be treated as a "one to many" relationship resulting in Match getting Players key and also a foreign key:

Match(key_of_player) -> (FK) -> Player(key_of_player)

[Entity Relationship Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvMzC.jpg)

Comment: The question is do you have just 22 per match? Whats about exchange players?

Comment: By exchange player, do you mean substitute? The scheme is intentionally not allowing for them. It is fixed at 22 per match.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "should"? 2. Please give a reference to the diagram notation you are using. (Your arrows are non-standard.) 3.Please type the text/DDL equivalent of your image into your question. What can be text should be text (even if supplemented by an image.)

Comment: After further investigation I found that constant (>1) to many is in fact, many to many.